# CMS: Made simple javascript support

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I've searched all over the internet to try and find an answer to my problem I have made a javascript down menu which emails the results to an email account the latter part of the functionality works but the drop down box validation doesn't I've tried using `{literal}{/literal}` tags as well as `{ldelim}{rdelim}` but none of this works.

I was just wondering whether CMSMS actually supports all javascript? FYI the javascript is syntactically correct it works in all 3 main browsers without an issue.

**(Edit) - This is part of the code that doesn't work in cmsms**

```
if(document.getElementById("device").value == "iPad 2")
{
    optionsChange2();
    colourChangeOther();
}

function optionsChange2()
{
    var select = document.getElementById('size');
    document.getElementById("size").options.length = 0;
    var options = ["Select a size", "16gb"];
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
    {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post a short example of code that does not work.

Comment: Ok @tibos my code is quite long but i can post a bit up.

Comment: Try to simplify it. Reduce it to a very dummy code that still exhibits your problem.